# Mapping the Linux keyboard to match MacOS keys

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-layout, macintosh, macos

I use a Linux PC at work but a MacBook at home, and the constant switch between keyboard layouts is bothersome. I would love a way to "remap" the keys of my Ubuntu computer so that they would function in the same way as my MacBook and feel "natural" to my fingers.

Basically, I would like the **Left Alt** key to function as a **Ctrl** key, the **Win** key as an **Option** key, and the Ctrl key as an Alt key. I'd also like the Caps Lock to toggle language input settings if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I played around with various command line tools but they're not particularly intuitive or friendly. Luckily I stumbled across a project on Github that works great and has a beautiful, simple GUI called "Key Mapper."

https://github.com/sezanzeb/key-mapper

It's available for various Linux distros. Here's an example of swapping the Alt key so that it now behaves as the MacOS "Command" key that would be in the same spot:

[image: Key Mapper screenshot]

Very simple and intuitive.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative tool for those who don't want to map the keys manually is [kinto.sh](https://kinto.sh/) ([GitHub repo](https://github.com/rbreaves/kinto)). I tried it on Fedora with Gnome on Xorg windowing system and it worked well. It is quite simple to install and you should get a macOS-like keyboard to work out of the box.

There is a catch though - at the time of writing, the tool doesn't support Wayland windowing system yet, only X11 and Xorg. The author mentioned adding the [support for Wayland](https://github.com/rbreaves/kinto/issues/420#issuecomment-797197985) but it seems like there is more work to be done, unfortunately.