# Keyboard: Remap macbook keys to match windows keyboard

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, macintosh

#### Backgrund

Reference: This is the opposite of [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/647729/mapping-the-linux-keyboard-to-match-macos-keys) question.

I installed Ubuntu on my Macbook. Unfortunately, the macbook has a very different keyboard layout than I am used to, in regard of function keys.

### Question

How do I map these keys on my Macbook keyboard:
[image]

to function as if they were these keys
[image: From the bottom left: ctrl, windows key (Super key), Alt.shift above ctrl, caps lock above shift]

**Because it is tempting:**
Please focus on the question. No questions like *why install on a macbook?* or *only use macos on a mac*.